# Can we do smallcaps in posts?

Tags: support, markdown

Is it possible to do smallcaps in questions and answers?

I recently [quoted a dictionary definition in EL&U](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/286364/need-colorful-synonym-for-dumbfounded-or-baffled/287426#287426) which ended with an example and citation along the lines of:

> ... **Now you sit there like a stunned mullet.* - BARRY DICKENS, 1985.

In the actual dictionary, the `BARRY DICKENS, 1985` bit was in smallcaps and I wanted to make it as close as possible, given the likely pedantic nature of EL&U people :-). And, as you can see, the capitalised full-size form sticks out like a sort thumb.

Now, I worked around it by putting `sub` and `sup` tags around the text as follows: `<sup><sub>TEXT</sub></sup>`:

> **Now you sit there like a stunned mullet.* <sup><sub>- BARRY DICKENS, 1985.</sub></sup>

That's not *too* bad but it elevates the text somewhat and I was just wondering whether there was a way to get the same effect but with the baseline lined up with the other text.

I have looked through the markdown help but found nothing to do with fonts, which is where I'd expect that to be.

Comment: If you want to play silly Unicode games, you can write "ʙᴀʀʀʏ ᴅɪᴄᴋᴇɴs". But I don't recommend actually doing that in a real post – for one thing, it makes the text effectively unsearchable.

Comment: Actually, that looks quite good, @Ilmari. The only thing missing from Unicode5.1 are `Q` and `X` which luckily don't appear in the name. And I don't really care about the searchability since that would only benefit Bazza himself and, having his own wikipedia page and a quote in Australia's national dictionary, he's obviously famous enough :-) In any case, the other things would be searchable still. I'd make that an answer rather than a comment, it's worth some rep IMO.

Comment: Related discussion on [meta.softwarerecs.se] about the Unicode characters: [**Small capital characters in posts**](http://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/2315/60)

Comment: Related feature request on [meta.english.se]: [**Proposal to add small-capitals formatting directive**](http://meta.english.stackexchange.com/q/2433/24906)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you start with the sub instead of the sup, as in

```
\**Now you sit there like a stunned mullet.* <sub><sup>- BARRY DICKENS, 1985.</sup></sub>
```

you will wind up with something like this:

> **Now you sit there like a stunned mullet.* <sub><sup>- BARRY DICKENS, 1985.</sup></sub>

Which is a bit closer to what you are after.

Comment: "closer"? Did you check the pixel distance? Just kidding. Though it still doesn't line up, it looks a little better being lower than being higher, at least to my eyes.

Comment: I tried one more `<sub></sub>` pair around the inside, but the result is unintelligible.